# Extracting data from a dictionary in bs4?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

name = input("Player's name: ")
url = f'https://www.futwiz.com/en/searches/career22/{name}'

r = requests.get(url)
print(r.content)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
results = soup.find(attrs={"lineid"})
print(results)
```

I can't get the data from the dictionary.
r.text looks like this:

> b'[{"lineid":"438","cardname":" Hakimi","name":"Achraf
> Hakimi","urlname":"achraf-hakimi","rating":"85","potential":"89","club":"73","pid":"235212","position":"RB","nation":"129","league":"16","acceleration":"93","agility":"84","balance":"79","jumping":"80","reactions":"84","sprintspeed":"95","stamina":"93","strength":"74","aggression":"75","positioning":"79","tactaware":"78","vision":"78","ballcontrol":"83","crossing":"86","curve":"77","dribbling":"81","finishing":"75","fkacc":"74","headingacc":"68","longpass":"73","longshot":"73","marking":"75","penalties":"60","shortpass":"81","shotpower":"80","slidetackle":"76","standingtackle":"78","volleys":"74","fname":"Achraf","lname":"Hakimi","dob":"22","height":"181","foot":"Right","traits":null,"teamname":"Paris
> Saint-Germain","leaguename":"France Ligue 1
> (1)","nationname":"Morocco","skillmoves":"3","weakfoot":"4"}]'

I'm trying to access "lineid" and get "438"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BeautifulSoup is a HTML parser, the response you're receiving is a JSON.

This script could help you:

```
import json
import requests

name = input("Player's name: ")
url = f'https://www.futwiz.com/en/searches/career22/{name}'

r = requests.get(url)
results = [line["lineid"] for line in json.loads(r.text)]
print(results)
```